# Pretty print XML response from REST API provided by Spring MVC

Tags: xml, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jaxb

Given is a method annotated with @GetMapping that returns an object with JAXB annotations.  For XML generation no additional libraries are added, i.e. the JDK built-in support is used. How can I enable pretty print XML output?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create your own HttpMessageConverter or use this one AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/AbstractJaxb2HttpMessageConverter.html) to include following property

```
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux you can pipe it through `xmllint --pretty 1 response.xml`.